# C# - Import reg file to the registry without user confirmation box

Tags: c#, registry

C# winforms - How can I import a *`reg`* file into the registry? The following code is displaying a confirmation box to the user (yes/no).

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("key.reg", "/S /q"); // not working
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Why shouldn't he do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Send the file as a parameter to `regedit.exe`:

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s key.reg");
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: One helpful hint, make sure the file name is enclosed with quotes if it contains spaces as it would on the command line.

Answer (score 15):

The code in answer 2 is correct, but not complete.
It will work when the directory where you are  refering to has no spacings in the path/file you are refering to example C:\ProgramFiles\key.reg will work fine, but C:\Program Files\key.reg WON'T WORK
because there are spaces in the path.

The solution:

```
string directory= @"C:\Program Files (x86)\key.reg";
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s \"" + directory + "\"");
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 8):

I tried to invoke RegEdit, but each time I got a confirm prompt (UAC enabled, no elevated permissions). Instead of RegEdit I recommand "reg.exe" (which is included in Windows since XP)

```
            Process proc = new Process();

            try
            {
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "reg.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                string command = "import " + path;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
                proc.Start();

                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                proc.Dispose();
            }
```

No dialog, no prompt.

The command is something like "reg import path/to/the/reg.reg"

Comment: Warning: There will be a malware called **HEUR/QVM03.0.0000.Malware.Gen** once you scanned your app with this method in [Virustotal](http://virustotal.com).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of executing a `.reg` file, you should be able to make your changes to the registry using the functionality provided in the [`Microsoft.Win32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.aspx) namespace.

It is quite easy to [create a registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) using this API:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

Unless you need to create a bulk load of new keys, I believe the API is a more scalable and maintable approach. If at some point, you need decide to make it optional to write your settings in the system-wide or the per-user branch of the registry, most of your code will be reusable for both cases. Simply pick another key to do the changes upon.

Maybe more important, the API lets you specify exactly (in code) how to handle cases where the key(s) you are inserting already exists in the registry. Should i delete the existing keys and insert mine, updates values within the existing keys, silently ignore or raise an exception?

Comment: Is there any particular reason he should be doing it using the API instead?

Comment: Assume the OP needs to install an official patch, which is a huge reg file. There are always valid reasons to do things.

Comment: I can tell is a huge reg file. thats way setValue for each can be pain in the *ss.

Comment: I agree with the three of you, that a `reg` is the right choice in some cases, and I have updated my answer with some arguments for why/when to use the API.