# How to use process.start to move values from registry

Tags: c#, registry, process.start

Using process.start i was trying to export some registry key to a file created in path `spath` by using following code, but it is not working , can any body tell me what is wrong here

```
rk = @HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\test\sim
File.Create(Path.Combine(spath, m_samview) + ".rtt");
Process ps1 = Process.Start("/C regedit.exe /e spath\\m_samview.rtt rk");
         ps1.WaitForExit();
         ps1.Close();
```

I checked link [proces.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171431/c-sharp-import-reg-file-to-the-registry-without-user-confirmation-box) based on that i did this work

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to just use the dedicated classes for manipulating the registry

Comment: @SimpleCoder i dont want any dedicated class, i just to want to trigger external process and do the task

Comment: @Bryan Crosby i hope syntax itself wrong here i believe

Comment: They are already built into the framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @SimpleCoder i dont understand the realtionship with that link.Registry doesnt have any functions in c# i beleive. I think regsavekeyx pinvoke is there, but i dont want it here. I need a simple code by using process.start

Comment: Oops, sorry - this link is better: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2003/Registry-handling-with-NET. That library can be used from within C#, no Pinvoke required.

Comment: @SimpleCode i dont think this will work, can anybody knows the systax of process.start

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the spath directly in the quote? Two things to try

- Format the command so that spath variable is resolved into actually path string
- If the path has space, please enclosed it (with the filename) within a quote

Example:

```
 string processString = string.Format("/C regedit.exe /e \"{0}\\m_samview.rtt\" rk", spath);
 Process ps1 = Process.Start(processString);
```

Comment: Sudama i used link http://jpreece.wordpress.com/csharp/how-to-export-a-registry-key/ ,but now i am getting error Cannot export '''''' Error opening the file. There may be a disk or file system error. can you tell me what is the reason

Comment: Now we are getting to very specific and I cant really help. I suggest that you debug the code and take the process string, analyse and run it manually in the command line. Compare it to the string/output you expect as according to that blog post

Comment: Sudama that i rectified. It was bit tricky, because File.Create() already created file and this code is going to create, that is the reason.I removed file.creat and run successfully

Answer (score 0):

With Process.Start you may need to provide the full path to the file. Try to point to \system32\regedit.exe rather than just regedit.exe

Comment: i did this way Process ps1 = Process.Start("/C regedit.exe /e spath\\m_samview.rtt rk"); but no luck. Actually here my file name is with m_samview property.

Comment: Why not just use Process.Start(filename, arguments). Make sure filename is pointing to full path to file