# Visual Studio - How to run files "in" the program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

How do I run programs "in" my program?

When I click a button, I want it to run a .reg file that I added to a folder in Visual Studio, like this:

[image: TestKey.reg is what I want to be ran when I click a button.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Import reg file to the registry without user confirmation box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171431/c-sharp-import-reg-file-to-the-registry-without-user-confirmation-box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [c# - Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should define a build action as "content" and "Copy file" field should be equal to "Always".
After that, you should use 
[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify your .reg file name in arguments.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"RegistryKeys\TestKey.reg");